# Generate JAVA/KOTLIN classes in android studio programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to generate a classes in android studio programmatically? like (generated data binding java classes).
If it is possible, how can I do this ?

Comment: Write an annotation processor, a Gradle plugin, or just an ordinary Gradle task (that you chain into the right part of the build process).

Comment: In addition to what CommonsWare mentioned, you can also take a look at [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-live-templates.html) if templating is your need.